# Securing sql server when impersonating windows users

Tags: sql-server, security, impersonation

I have implemented an audit table in my sql server 2008 database using [this technique](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/) which works exactly as I would want.

However, it relies on SYSTEM_USER to determine the username to write to the audit.

I am connecting to the database through an ASP.NET application, and am impersonating the windows user account in IIS to pass with the database using an integrated security = true connection. To enable the user to access the database I have had to grant them db_datareader and db_datawriter access.

This allows the audit to work as desired, however, I am concerned about security. How can I prevent a user connecting to the database using excel and reading all data?

Basically I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. Easily log audit records the windows user
2. Secure data access from anywhere other than my application

From my understanding I can have one or the other, not both.

If I allow access from the windows user I can easily audit, but data is insecure. If I connect with a specific service account the data is more secure, but the audit would not work as required.

Can anyone suggest a way of accomplishing both?

Comment: Just a quick observation or two:  since your asp.net app uses impersonation for connecting to SQL Server, your audit table will always show the same value for `UserName`, right?  Does this gain you anything?  Your asp.net app needs both read & write permissions whether you implement auditing or not.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'll check the Username behaviour tomorrow and report back. And you're right in thinking the app needs read and write for other functionality too. Thanks for your reply.